# jquery selector for previous instance of a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

on a button click event, i want to read the value of a textbox based on a certain class.  there are multiple textboxes with that class on the page so i want to grab the one that is before the button. NOTE: this is NOT directly before but i want it to search up the page until it find an instance.

i thought [Prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) would do this but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: and what if you use another selector within the class one?

Comment: Have you tried [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).prevAll('.class:first');
```

Use `prevAll` with a `:first` filter

Comment: this doesn't seem to work  . .i am getting jquery() when i look in firebug at the result of this selector

Comment: @ooo you _should_ get jquery as a return. jQuery always gives you the wrapped jQuery object. Have a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/H32gk/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have unknown nesting and the text boxes are *not* siblings, try this:

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    var allElem = $("*");
    var buttonIndex = allElem.index(this);
    var nearest;
    $(".text").each(function(i, elm) {
        var index = allElem.index(elm);
        if (buttonIndex > index) {
            nearest = elm;
        }
    });
    alert($(nearest).val());
});
```

This relies on the index of the element and finds the one that is closest to your button.  I am sure there is some sort of awesome selector for this, hopefully someone will post it `:)`

**[Code example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/rWx8Z/2/)**